# Mobile keypad permutation (SEGMENTATION FAULT) using vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve a challenge problem using vector implementation. But somehow I'm getting segmentation fault when I try to store the string in vector.

This particular line is causing issue **lar.push_back(l)**

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    vector <string> temp;
    int n;

    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];
  vector  <string> ar ;
//{"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno","pqrs","tuv","wxyz"};
ar.push_back("abc");
ar.push_back("def");
ar.push_back("ghi");
ar.push_back("jkl");
ar.push_back("mno");
ar.push_back("pqrs");
ar.push_back("tuv");
ar.push_back("wxyz");


   vector <string> lar;

int p=1;
while(p<=n)
{

  if(p==1)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<ar[arr[n-2]-2].length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<ar[arr[n-1]-2].length();j++)
        {
            char s=ar[arr[n-2]-2][i];
            char h=ar[arr[n-1]-2][j];
            string l;
            l.push_back(s);
            l.push_back(h);
            lar.push_back(l);

        }

    }
    n=n-1;
}
else
    {
     for(int i=0;i<ar[arr[n-2]-2].length();i++)
         {
            for( int j=0;lar.size();j++)
            {
             char s=ar[arr[n-2]-2][i];
             string t;
             t.push_back(s);
             string z=s+lar[j];
             //t.push_back("aaa");
             temp.push_back(z);
            // temp.push_back(lar[j]);

            }
         }
        lar=temp;
    }


p++;
}

for(int i=0;lar.size();i++)
  cout<<lar[i]<<" ";



}

    return 0;
}
```

when I gave input as

```
1
2
2 3
```

output is : aa ab ac ba bb bc ca cb cc (with segmantation fault)

but when I give input as

```
1
3
2 3 4
```

No output is given  and segmentation fault is occur.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in the final part of the code:

```
for(int i=0;lar.size();i++)
```

should be:

```
for(int i=0;i<lar.size();i++)
```

Else the loop is unterminated, hence it reaches areas of lar which are unpopulated, and consequently there is an invalid read, and as a result there's a segfault.

There seems to be an additional problem too which I am tracking down.

I've found a second issue in the else{ } section, you've got:

```
string z=s+lar[j];
```

but the j was from a previous loop. This line is crashing too.

I have to say though, the code doesn't work even when you change it to:

```
string z=s+lar[i];
```

I suspect the algorithm has a design flaw. It's still better code than the utter drivel Lennart Poettering throws into linux though.

Comment: What about the other one for the j loop where there is a loop with the length of 3 dimensional array? In the else part. Not used but same mistake.

Comment: Linda Lambie good point! It was trashing GDB's backtrace, so it was a little more time consuming to find.